# Losing model data when navigating to next page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using paging with ASP.NET MVC, but I'm losing model data when navigating to next page.

Here is the code:

Partial view:

```
@using PagedList;

@using PagedList.Mvc;

@model Models.MyObject

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<table class="table table-striped table-hover sortable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="240">@Model.HeaderNames[0]</th>
        <th width="240">@Model.HeaderNames[1]</th>
        <th width="240">@Model.HeaderNames[2]</th>
        <th width="240">@Model.HeaderNames[3]</th>
        <th width="120" class="no-sort"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var member in Model.PagedModelList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><span class="sort-field-value">@member.Thead1</span></td>
            <td><span class="sort-field-value">@member.Thead2</span></td>
            <td><span class="sort-field-value">@member.Thead3</span></td>
            <td><span class="sort-field-value">@member.Thead4</span></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<footer>
   <div>

    Page @(Model.PagedModelList.PageCount < Model.PagedModelList.PageNumber 
? 0 : Model.PagedModelList.PageNumber) of @Model.PagedModelList.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model.PagedModelList, page =>Url.Action("Reports",new { @page = page, FirstLoad = false }))
   </div>
</footer>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Reports(MyObject model, int? page, bool FirstLoad = true)
{
        model.pageSize = 4;
        model.pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        if (FirstLoad)
        {
            // getting the data from database here 
            // ... code

            // assigning pagemodelist
            model.PagedModelList = model.ModelList.ToPagedList(model.pageNumber, model.pageSize);
        }

        // here sending the model and all is good
        return PartialView("_MyView", model);
    }
```

Model

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int SelectedPeriod { get; set; }
    public List<SecondObject> ModelList = new List<Secondobject>();
    public IPagedList<Secondobject> PagedModelList ;

    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Second model class:

```
public class SecondObject
{
    public string Thead1 { get; set; }
    public string Thead2 { get; set; }
    public string Thead3 { get; set; }
    public string Thead4 { get; set; }
}
```

Expected to get next page but all I get is empty model which causes null reference when sending again to view from controller. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm getting right data in model the first time, I show the table with correct data, then when clicking on next page I debug in the controller so I got empty `model.PagedModelList`, even some other empty model properties .

Any help appreciated

Comment: you should write else condition and assign values to model.PagedModelList

Comment: what do you mean assign values , i want the the real values .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try to pass your model in parameters like :

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.PagedModelList, page =>Url.Action("Reports",new {@model = Model, @page = page, FirstLoad = false }))
```

**Edit :**
Another solution is to remove MyObject from parameters. 
Load each time your data from your database. You can follow the example in
[GitHub project](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList)

Comment: tried but im getting same result , null model , maybe its not encoding right i dont know